# How many sequences in a prefix code can be compressed by m bits?

Tags: coding-theory

I have a little understanding problem with Appendix A ("Universal Codes") in the paper "Shannon Information and Kolmogorov complexity" by Gründwald and Vitanyi ([Link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0410002.pdf)).

At the end of page 50, they say something corresponding to:

> For each Prefix-code, the fraction of sequences of length $n$ that can be compressed by more than $m$ bits is less than $2^{-m}$.

Either this is a writing mistake or I should make a break from reading.

It is easy to see, that the number of strings with length $n$ and compression length smaller than $m$ is smaller $2^{m-n}$ for a prefix-code because there are simple not enough "shorter" words.. Did they mean this information?

It is also easy to understand, that the Kraft-Inequality $\sum_{x\in X}2^{-l(x)}\leq1$ holds for a prefix code  with source word set $X$ and the compression length $l(x)$ for strings $x\in X$.

Is that only a writing mistake? Respectively can you tell me an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the statement. An *encoding* $f$ of the set of strings of length $n$ is a map from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ which is injective (one-to-one). Such a mapping *compresses a string $x$ by more than $m$* if $|f(x)| < |x| - m$. In our case, all the strings have length $n$, so a string $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ is compressed by more than $m$ if $|f(x)| < n-m$. There are $\sum_{i=0}^{n-m-1} 2^i = 2^{n-m}-1 < 2^{n-m}$ such strings, and since $f$ is injective, the fraction of strings compressed by more than $m$ is less than $2^{n-m}/2^n = 2^{-m}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstand the the statement "compresses a string by more than m" to $|f(x)|<m$ instead of $|f(x)|<n-m$. Thanks again.